# Is conservation of energy a local law in Quantum field theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, energy-conservation, conservation-laws, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, locality

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_of_energy),

> "The local energy conservation in quantum field theory is ensured by the quantum Noether's theorem for the energy-momentum tensor operator. Thus energy is conserved by the normal unitary evolution of a quantum system."

I know that it is the case in GR that conservation of energy and other conservation laws are relegated to being local only I thought this wasn't the case in quantum field theory.

Comment: Noether's theorem means that energy is conserved because of time-translation invariance of the Lagrangian. This conservation is expressed locally, but is global. Hope what I said makes sense.

Comment: Related/worth checking https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/143892/226902

Comment: @NikosM. I'm sorry could you explain what you mean by "expressed locally, but is global" If it's no trouble ofc.

Comment: @KleinMoretti conservation is global but changes occur locally. That is decrease in one place leads to increase in nearby place.

Comment: @NikosM. so you are saying that CE does hold globally and its actually local CE that has has problems?

Comment: @KleinMoretti did not say anything has problems

Comment: @NikosM. oh sorry, I guess I misunderstood your answer, basically you are saying that at CE hold both globally and locally right?

Comment: @KleinMoretti strictly speaking conservation is only global, but changes are local. At least that is Noether's theorem which defines a conservation current for conserved quantities.

Comment: @NikosM. it's just that the answer given by Valter conflicts with this, or at least I think it does maybe im just an idiot

Comment: @KleinMoretti note I am referring to QM while Valter refers to GR (not necessarily compatible). But I am asking myself if we are saying the same thing and we are simply lost in translation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the **stress energy tensor operator**, also in curved spacetime, satisfies  the *local conservation equation* in a distributional sense $$\nabla_a :\hat{T}^{ab}:_{\omega}(x)=0\:,\tag{1}$$ where the "normal order" is referred to a (vacuum) Gaussian (Hadamard) state $\omega$.

I wrote a work on that many years ago which proves that also at the level of *-algebras of operators (I considered only the KG field, but the procedures can be extended to all types of fields).

Theorem 2.1 (with $V' \equiv 0$) in
https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s00220-002-0702-7.pdf

There is also an [arXives version](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0109048).

(1) implies a global conservation law in the presence of a **timelike** Killing field $K$
$$\int_\Sigma \langle \Psi| :\hat{T}^{ab}:(x) \Psi \rangle K_a n_b d\Sigma(x)  = constant$$
where $n$ is the unit vector normal to the Cauchy surface $\Sigma$,
for every state $\Psi$ on a suitable domain  in the Hilbert space of the GNS representation of $\omega$. It is not obvious that the integral is finite.

Concerning the issue of conservation laws in GR, they exist when Killing vector fields exist. Properly speaking,  (1) is **not** a *conservation* law as it stands: in the sense of the equivalence principle is, but not in the sense of the Noether theorem.

However it becomes a conservaqtion law in proper sense if there is a Killing vector field.   Let us prove it.

A conservation law is of the form $$\nabla_a J^a =0\tag{2}. $$ If this identity holds, the divergence theorem proves that
$$\int_\Sigma J^a n_a d\Sigma = constant \tag{2'}$$
on Cauchy surfaces $\Sigma$, where $n$ is the unit vector normal to $\Sigma$. Obviously it is also necessary that the integral converges
(Actually, even if it diverges, we may also consider it a global conservation law: the charge is aways infinite. It depends on personal taste.)

Equation $\nabla_a T^{ab}=0$ does not automatically imply (2). However, if there is a Killing field $K$, so that the **Killing equation** is valid
$$\nabla_a K_b + \nabla_b K_a =0 \tag{3}\:,$$
then  $J^a:= K_bT^{ba}$ (where $T^{ab}=T^{ba}$) satisfies (2).
$$\nabla_a (K_bT^{ba}) = (\nabla_a K_b) T^{ba} + K_b  \nabla_aT^{ba} =
\frac{1}{2}(\nabla_a K_b  + \nabla_b K_a )  \: T^{ba} +0 =0\:.$$

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151822/discussion-on-answer-by-valter-moretti-is-conservation-of-energy-a-local-law-in); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.